# How to configure amount of command history saved by GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci

By default, GHCi saves 100 lines of command history in `~/.ghc/ghci_history`.  Can I increase this number?

I'm using GHC 7.6.3 on GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On my system (GNU/Linux, GHC 7.6.3), GHCi is built against the [haskeline](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline) library. According to [this document](http://trac.haskell.org/haskeline/wiki/UserPrefs), it can be customised by editing the `~/.haskeline` file:

`maxhistorysize: Just 1000`

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Strangely, I couldn't test it automatically, e.g. `{ seq 1 200 | xargs -n1 ; echo ':quit' } | ghci` doesn't save any history at all, and truncates the existing history file to 100 lines, regardless of the `maxhistorysize` setting.  But, opening up ghci and mashing the keyboard for a while verified that the history file has grown above 100 lines :D

Comment: IIUC, haskeline [switches itself off automatically](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline-0.7.1.1/src/System/Console/Haskeline/InputT.hs) when `stdin` is a pipe.

Comment: Interesting. The docs for the `preferTerm` variable in the file indicate that one might be able to configure GHCi to save history even when reading from a pipe.  Of course, I don't have any use for that besides my stupid test :P

Comment: This also works on Windows. Just put the line above in `C:\Users\YourName\.hakeline`.

Comment: 1000 seems very conservative, especially with hard drives being so cheap... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As discussed this is the solution for Mac OSX, the other answer is for Linux. I found what your looking for [here](http://bernhardwagner.blogspot.com/2009/03/vi-command-line-history-in-ghci.html) basically copy pasting the relevant information and formatting it below here.

The default is a history of 100 commands but you can change that by adding this line to your `~/.ghc/ghci.conf:`

`System.Console.Editline.Readline.stifleHistory 1000`

which would increase your history to 1000 commands.

Comment: This does not work on my system, I think because my GHCi is using `readline` and your trick is for `editline`. The module `System.Console.Editline.Readline` is not installed, and trying to install it with `cabal install editline` gives a compile error, because editline is not installed. Installing the editline lib with `sudo aptitude install libeditline-dev` does not help.

Comment: There is a [Haskell Readline lib](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/readline-1.0.3.0/docs/System-Console-Readline.html), but I can't find a "amount of saved history" command there.

Comment: @ntc2 interesting! now we know the mac solution and the linux solution!